# htaccess redirect if query string exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

need to redirect from index page if only it contains query string

example: http://example.com/?id=q2w2 to http://example.com/page.php/?id=q2w2
but not from http://example.com/

my rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+) [NV]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /page.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

it redirects from any page to http://example.com/page.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=.+
RewriteRule ^/?$ /page.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301]
```

Start testing using a 302 redirection first until you are certainly everything works fine. That way you prevent caching issues...

Comment: it works the same, redirecting pages with & without query :(

Comment: 1. make sure you are not looking at a cached result (use a fresh anonymous browser tab), 2. check your http server's error log file and 3. please document in the question (there is an "edit" link...) where exactly you implemented that rule.